# How to enable media queries on IE < 9

Tags: internet-explorer, css3, responsive-webdesign, media-queries

I am trying to add support for media queries in older versions of Internet Explorer, but I am not having any luck. I only need media queries, so I do not want to add a big package like Modernizr, I am looking for a small fix, if there is any.

Anyone know a good method?

Comment: Can you explain what version(s) of IE you are talking about? Older versions do not support it but IE9 does.

Comment: Oh yes I am talking about 8,7 and 6 if possible. I edited it into the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search turns up this: [Respond.js: Fast CSS3 Media Queries for Internet Explorer 6-8 and more](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/respondjs_fast_css3_media_queries_for_internet_explorer_6_8_and_more/) and [css3-mediaqueries-js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/).

Comment: OK, I was actually looking for a method without JavaScript, but I do not think that is an option.

Comment: Ok, I tried both, but like a few I have tried, they completely break the website. You have to load them in a specific order, and the mediaqueries have to be deigned in a specific way. Respond.js works from bottom to top, I design my sited from top to bottom. I have to redesign everything in order to have these scripts work, and even then they do not work 100%. Thanks for the Google search.

Comment: what way do you need to design your media queries?